# Botão curtir não carrega conteudo

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Tenho o botão curtir do Facebook no site, porem quando entra na pagina e clico em curtir o conteúdo fica em branco. Se atualizar a pagina o conteúdo aparece.

segue o código:

### Script

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```